# NodeJs mySql fetch only one result

Tags: mysql, node.js

I expect **only one** result from this mySQL query.

Is it possible to fetch the result into vars without a `forEach` ?

```
pmSql.query("SELECT name FROM sqlTable LIMIT 1", function(err, rows, fields) {
  rows.forEach(function(row) { // don't want this forEach, I expect only 1
    console.log(row.name); // it's only one!
  });
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sure,

instead of forEach,  you can try as shown below

```
if(rows.length == 1) {
    var row = rows[0];
}
```

and if you are damn sure about, the result is one, then you can avoid the if check